# Effects of Setting a Lower Bound on the Fourier Transform of a Function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

We are concerned with a function in 2-D Euclidean space. $\theta: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ $, $\theta \in  L^1(\mathbb{R}^2) \cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^2) $, $p\in (2,\infty)$.

As per the title, I am wondering if there are any properties $\theta$ attains, if we set $\hat{\theta}(\xi) \geq 0$, $\forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I am wondering if there are any other strange properties that might be forced on $\theta$ by messing with its FT in this way. I am not overly familiar with the intricacies of the FT, and so am very curious as to how general $\theta$ can still be with this condition applied to it.

To give some background, I am using the $\theta$ I am talking about here as the initial data to the Quasi-Geostrophic Equations; and so I am wary of forcing the FT to have this property, for fear of being left with very strong conditions on my initial data.

EDIT: It is sufficient for my purposes to simply set $\hat{\theta}$ positive, not bounded from below by a positive constant as was originally written!

Comment: Do you mean $\theta: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$? Otherwise, how are you defining the Fourier transform of a vector-valued function?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: For starters you are forcing the Fourier transform to be real, which is only possible here if $\theta$ is an even function, i.e., $\theta(x) = \theta(-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. But also $\theta$ is real so the Fourier transform is also even.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. Just to be sure, this doesn't force $\theta$ to be radially symmetric, right?

Comment: I don't think so. $\hat \theta$ is radially symmetric iff $\theta$ is radially symmetric.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much